# compilation error while compiling c++ program on Fedora 14

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, compiler-construction, g++

I succesfully install fedora14 using virtual box,but I could'nt compile anything by using g++ command it says "command not found",how can I solve this?

I have to mention here i followed as 
1)type- su
then I enter p.w
2)type- yum install g--c++

but its not working

Answer (score 1):

This means g++ is not available on your machine.You should try the following step to install

> 1. sudo yum install gcc-c++
> 2. enter root password
> 3. Once installation is complete, verify by the command "gcc -v" and "man g++".

Comment: I will try.By the way now feodra is not working when I just try to click start button on virtual box...still it starting....